# What's the quickest way to remove an element from a Map By Key in Java?

Tags: java

There is a Object of Example, the filed id is unique.

And I Suppose there are many elements in the map,  What's the quickest way to remove an example of id = 1 from the map.

```java
public class Solution {

    @Data
    public static class Example {
        // unique key
        int    id;
        Object filed;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Suppose there are many elements in the map
        HashMap<Example, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        int id = 1;
        Example example = new Example();
        example.setId(id);
        map.put(example, new Object());

        // How to quickly delete example of id = 1


        System.out.println(map);
    }

}
```

Comment: If the `id` of `Example` is the unique identifier, then override [`Object::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`Object::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) in `Example` to conform to this specification. Then, call [`Map::remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Why not make it a `HashMap<Integer, Object>` and write `map.put(example.id, ...)` to store things there? Then you can just do `map.remove(id)`.

Answer (score -4):

You must override `equals` and `hashCode` method in `Example` class. Post which when you will invoke map.remove(example) it will remove it. In your `equals` and `hashCode` method you must use field `id` as equality or comparison factor.

```
class Example {
    
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Example)) return false;
    Example that = (Example) o;
    return id == that.id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}
}
```

Note: Above is not a compiled code and just a snippet.

Comment: This is a faulty implementation of `equals`. It should have `Object` as parameter.

Comment: Furthermore, we cannot call `hashCode()` on an `int`

Comment: @Turing85 - That was just to give an idea. Never intended to provide a full working implementation. I did mention in the note below

Comment: Either way: the "solution" is dangerous since this a hard bug to find. I would suggest to at least mention the risk if one does not properly override `equals`.